# I only have *.pem and *.key files, how to make sure the http client is not attacked

Tags: go, ssl, key, pem

I only got the two files `*.pem` and `*.key` through the certificate authority.

I am worried about man-in-the-middle attacks, which will replace the certificate and deceive the client, so I wrote the following code, the client directly reads the *.pem file and compares the certificate obtained by http to ensure that the connection is correct when they are the same.

I would like to know if my solution is correct and if there is a better solution to my problem?

`server code`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello %s", time.Now().String())
    })

    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", `xx.pem`, `xx.key`, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

`client code`

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    err := getPem()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = httpGet()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

var (
    pemRawCerts [][]byte // xx.pem读取的原始数据
    errCheckPem = errors.New("check xx.pem error")
)

func getPem() error {
    certPEMBlock, err := os.ReadFile(`xxx.pem`)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var certDERBlock *pem.Block
    for {
        certDERBlock, certPEMBlock = pem.Decode(certPEMBlock)
        if certDERBlock == nil {
            break
        }

        if certDERBlock.Type == "CERTIFICATE" {
            tmp := make([]byte, len(certDERBlock.Bytes))
            copy(tmp, certDERBlock.Bytes)
            pemRawCerts = append(pemRawCerts, tmp)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func httpGet() error {
    c := http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                VerifyPeerCertificate: func(data [][]byte, verifiedChains [][]*x509.Certificate) error {
                    if len(data) == len(pemRawCerts) {
                        for i := len(data) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
                            if !bytes.Equal(data[i], pemRawCerts[i]) {
                                return errCheckPem
                            }
                        }
                        // Only when every item of the certificate is correct can the current connection be determined to be ok
                        return nil
                    }
                    return errCheckPem
                },
            },
        },
    }

    resp, err := c.Get("https://janbar.com")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    n, err := io.Copy(io.Discard, resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(n)
    return err
}
```

Comment: The server code is correct. The client code needs to add a `RootCA` to the `tls.Config` to verify the servers identify. The rootca can either be nil - using the system default trust chain - or create a custom one. If you are using a private certificate authority, the root CA trust cert should be available for this purpose.

Comment: @colm.anseo  I know what you said, but the certificate authority only gave me two files, pem and key. I don't have a ca certificate. If the certificate of the man-in-the-middle attack can also be verified by the root certificate, there should be a problem.